# Possible to create textarea with num of rows and wrapping

Tags: html, textarea, word-wrap

I'm wondering if is it possible to emulate common desktop editor (like gedit or Textmate) in textarea, when there are two major requirements:

1. counting of rows by the side of text editor
2. indication of wrapping

Image best ilustrate what I'm talking about:

[image: text editor]

I want to create area for entering lots of text on the webpage and due to nature of texts (human language) it is required, that users needn't to place newline (RETURN \n) to fit long sentences to screen (creating megalong lines with horizontal scrollbar is unaccetable).

All textarea numbering "tools" (jQuery plugins etc.) are suitable only for computer languages, where long lines are not so common and all commands are separated by newline. But for better UX when writting human language (blogpost for example) it is better to setup wrapping on textarea. But in this scenarions all JS row numbering sollutions fails.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use either [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/) or [ACE](http://ace.ajax.org/).